# How to escape three dots in bash script using git command

Tags: git, bash, shell, escaping, sh

I have a problem to execute a git command using shell script. I need to execute the following command:

```
git log $1...$2
```

where $1 and $2 are tags from any git project version. I know that the problem is in using those three dots in shell script. Using the command above results in something like this:

**Example - Dagger git project from google repository**

```
git log --pretty=%h dagger-2.3...dagger-2.4..
```

**This command results in:**

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'dagger-2.3...dagger-2.4...': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git < command > [< revision >...] -- [< file >...]'

Passing the **-x** to my bash script show me the following message :

> + git log --pretty=%h dagger-2.3...dagger-2.4...

**How can i solve this? I need take all hashes commits between two tags**

Comment: I don't think your problem is what you think it is, but in any case, a [mcve] would help others help you.

Comment: The problem isn't with the shell; the problem its that `dagger-2.4..` just isn't a valid revision name.

Comment: But when i execute the same command in terminal this works properly

Comment: So, @chepner you're right. I note now that there's some extra dots when i pass the arguments to my script. thank you =) .. it's an stupid mistake that i did.